# How to change the default landing page after serve command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am wondering if it is possible to change the default startup address after the command

```
php artisan serve
```

Because when I run it, I get the default url

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

But my "first page" is when I type

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/index
```

in the browser.

So is it possible to automatically give out `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` after startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show your `index.blade.php` at first place then just replace in your `routes/web.php`

From this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
```

TO this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Comment: Ah so it is that's easy? I thought it is some special command where I need to change  something in the config file